# su in script redirecting it to the super user directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

When I do `su` in my script it is exiting the script and giving to the `su` directory..after exiting super directory, the commands after the `su - user1`  are executing when I exit the super directory..please help

```
if [ $owner = "user1" ]
then
    su - user1 <<HERE
cd $LOG_DOR
cat $job.log
HERE
else
    echo "$owner not found"
fi

## I have multiple super users based on the given job
```

Comment: Why do you include `'-'` which *"Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login"*? and *"changes to the target user's home directory"*  -- Get rid of the `'-'`. Just do `su user1`.

Comment: Tried that getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ $owner = "user1" ]
then
    su -c "cd $LOG_DOR; cat $job.log" - user1
else
    echo "$owner not found"
fi
```

> -c, --command COMMAND
>              Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.
>
> The executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option
>   cannot be used to execute interactive programs which need a
>   controlling TTY.